# changing IFS temporarily before a for loop

Tags: bash, for, assignment

I know that the `SHELL` allows variable assignment to take place immediately before a command, such that `IFS=":" read a b c d <<< "$here_string"` works...

What I was wondering is do such assignments not work when done with compound statements such as loops? I tried something like `IFS=":" for i in $PATH; do echo $i; done` but it results in a syntax error. I could always do something like `oldIFS="$IFS"; IFS=":"; for....; IFS="$oldIFS"`, but I wanted to know if there was any way I could make such inline assignments work for compound statements like `for` loops?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`for` is a reserved word and as such follows [special rules](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04):

> The following words shall be recognized as reserved words:
>
> **!  { } case do done elif else esac fi for if in then until while**
>
> This recognition shall only occur when none of the characters is quoted and when the word is used as:
>
> - The first word of a command
> - The first word following one of the reserved words other than **case**, **for**, or **in**
> - The third word in a case command (only **in** is valid in this case)
> - The third word in a for command (only **in** and **do** are valid in this case)

If you try

```
IFS=":" for i in $PATH; do echo $i; done
```

then by the rules above that is not a `for` loop, as the keyword is not
the first word of the command. But you can get the desired output with

```
tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"               #Bash, Ksh, Zsh
printf "%s\n" "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'   #Any standard shell
```

where `tr` replaces each `:` by a newline.

---

You may be familiar with this valid approach:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
```

`while` is the first word of the command, and the `IFS` assignment applies to `read`,
so all is OK.

Comment: Regarding the `while` loop solution... For POSIX sh: Use a here document (`<<`) to input a variable into the loop. Don't do `echo "$example" | while ...` because that creates a subshell and won't maintain variable state out of the loop. Bash has here string (`<<<`) support so use that if available.

Answer (score 0):

Shell macro assignements are permitted before simple commands (such as `read`) but not before compound statements like `for`.

It is recommanded to use:

```
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
some complex commands
IFS=$OIFS
```